# Friedman's Test fails inspite of big differences between the average ranks of algorithms

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, friedman-test

I performed `Friedman's test` to validate that a particular algorithm is statistically different from other compared algorithms.

For example:
I wanted to prove my algorithm A is significantly different from other algorithms across different datasets. So I tabulate the performances similar to,

```
             Algorithm A   Algorithm B .....   Algorithm N
 Dataset A      
 Dataset B
   .
   .
 Dataset k
 Average rank  r_A            r_B                 r_N
```

Now if `r_A` (average rank of algorithm A) is much different than others (i.e. it's value is closer to N or 1 and other ranks are much away from `r_A`), then we can guess that the Friedman's test will more likely reject `Null Hypothesis`. But surprisingly, I figured that the test fails to reject the null hypothesis in spite of having at least one algorithm or group excessively different from others. However when applying `Wilcoxon ranksum test` the significance is absorbed and rejected the null hypothesis as expected.

Numerical example:

Average ranks of 7 algorithms are: `[5.66, 5.16, 4.66, 4.83, 2.66, 4, 1]`
Following [Demsar-2006](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v7/demsar06a.html) notations: Friedman statistic is computed 
for `k = 7, N = 3` and found to be around `2.433` and Critical value from F-distribution table is around `2.99`. And to reject the null hypothesis, Friedman statistic should be greater than the critical value, hence it failed to reject null hypothesis in spite of the significant difference of the seventh algorithm from others.

It is very much appreciated if someone suggests the piece I missed or correct my wrong understanding in any part. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: (1) How are the algorithms measured numerically?  In particular, is there an appreciable chance of ties in their values (and if so, have you corrected the test statistic for ties)?  (2) The F distribution is only an approximation for large $n$ and large $k.$  It's not plausible that $n=3$ is sufficiently "large" for this purpose. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test. (3) Could you show how you computed the statistic of $2.433$?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example of the behavior you are seeing, not with just the average ranks, but with all the observations....  If you are looking for a test more akin to the rank sum test, you might consider the Quade test.